Redirect and rollback stderr in unit tests
For the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int old_std;
void redirect()
{
    old_std = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
    assert(old_std != -1);    // fails when the redirect is called 2nd time.
    freopen("test.txt", "w", stderr);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
}

void revert()
{
    fclose(stderr);
    stderr = fdopen(old_std, "w");
    fflush(stderr);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    redirect();
    // testing logic
    revert();
    redirect();
    // testing logic
    revert();
    return 0;
}

I would like to test some logic with stderr. To make it automatically, I tried to redirect the stderr before the testing logic, and revert the stderr when testing is done.
However, the second time I do this, the system crashes when the second redirect is called. I am not familiar with freopen and dup, so I guess there might be something wrong aobut my logic. Can anybody provide a stable way to redirect & revert the stderr during unit testing?

dup(STDERR_FILENO) should be dup(fileno(stderr))

Assigning to stderr is not portable.  Per footnote 272 of the (draft) C11 standard: "The primary use of the freopen function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned."

Don't bother.  Instead of dup, use fork and run the tests in a child.

When you call
    old_std = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

, you create a new file descriptor that refers to the same open file description that STDERR_FILENO does.
When you call
    freopen("test.txt", "w", stderr);

you associate a different file with stderr, first closing the original stream.  You have retained access to the original stderr by dup()ing its file descriptor, but the freopen() closes the original one, leaving STDERR_FILENO not corresponding to a valid file descriptor.
That's ok the first time, but it means that the second time, the dup(STDERR_FILENO) is erroneous at best.  At worst, it dupes a valid file descriptor associated with something else.
Now, when you call
    stderr = fdopen(old_std, "w");

you associate the duped file descriptor then stored in old_std with a new stream and assign that to stderr.  This is ok (more or less), and it means that afterward, you could access the file descriptor associated with the original stderr via fileno(stderr), as indeed would have worked on the first call too.  One solution, then, would be @Barmar's suggestion to dupe differently:
    old_std = dup(fileno(stderr));

That is pretty obviously right for duping the file descriptor of whatever file is presently associated with stderr, as long as there is one.
However, you are presently relying on stderr being assignable (which C does not guarantee).  If you are going to persist in that, then you can save yourself some confusion by just handling the stderr swapping at the stream level:
FILE *original_stderr;

void redirect() {
    stderr = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    if (stderr == NULL) {
        stderr = original_stderr;
        perror("test.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
}

void revert() {
    fclose(stderr);
    stderr = original_stderr;
}

int main() {
    original_stderr = stderr;
    redirect();
    // do stuff ...
    revert();
    redirect();
    // do other stuff ...
    revert();
}


Given footnote 272, it'd probably be a lot simpler to ignore stderr and just use some combination of old_std = dup(STDERR_FILENO);, then int new_fd = open( "stderr.captured", ...); dup2(new_fd, STDERR_FILENO); and then restore stderr with dup2(old_std, STDERR_FILENO).

I don't think that's particularly simpler, @AndrewHenle, but did I consider something along those lines.  If, as the OP, I were not satisfied with relying on assigning to stderr, then that would be a reasonable alternative.  However, I'm not sure where to find any documentation guaranteeing that duping an open file descriptor onto that of an existing stream will have the desired effect on the stream.  It does, in my experience, but if that's not documented then it's not clear that that approach would be any better for portability.

POSIX stderr links the values. Also makes typing STDERR_FILENO extraneous.  It will be 2.

You can't assume you can assign to stderr with code such as
stderr = fdopen(old_std, "w");

Per footnote 272 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note272):

The primary use of the freopen function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned.

On a POSIX system, it's a lot easier to just redirect the STDERR_FILENO file descriptor to a file and leave the FILE *stderr as-is.
Per POSIX 7 stderr :

The following symbolic values in <unistd.h> define the file descriptors that shall be associated with the C-language stdin, stdout, and stderr when the application is started:

STDIN_FILENO
    Standard input value, stdin. Its value is 0.
STDOUT_FILENO
    Standard output value, stdout. Its value is 1.
STDERR_FILENO
    Standard error value, stderr. Its value is 2. 


Something like this:
(deliberately formatted to limit/remove any vertical scroll bar - I do not recommend cramming actual working code into as few lines as possible like this)
static int savedStderr = -1;

int restoreStderr( void )
{
    if ( savedStderr < 0 ) return( -1 );

    int rc = dup2( savedStderr, STDERR_FILENO );
    if ( rc == -1 ) return( -1 );

    return( 0 );
}

int redirectStderr( const char *filename )
{
    // add O_EXCL, O_TRUNC or O_APPEND as desired
    int fd = open( filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644 );
    if ( fd < 0 ) return( -1 );

    int savedStderr = dup( STDERR_FILENO );
    if ( savedStderr == -1 ) return( -1 );

    int rc = dup2( fd, STDERR_FILENO );
    if ( rc == -1 ) {
        restoreStderr();
        return( -1 );
    }
 
    return( 0 );
}

    

